# MYSQL JOIN all child rows and display parent row once only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have a simple article and comments system with the following tables:

Articles table:

```
id | writer | text
 1 | Bob    | first article
 2 | Marley | second article
```

Comments table:

```
id | article_id | comment
 1 |      1     |  i love this article
 2 |      1     |  good one
 3 |      2     |  waiting for more
```

I want to select each article with its comments underneath it. I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles LEFT JOIN comments ON articles.id = comments.article_id
```

The results I get:

```
 articles.id   | articles.writer | articles.text  | comments.id | comments.article_id | comments.comment
 1             | Bob             | first article  |    1        |         1           | i love this article
 1             | Bob             | first article  |    2        |         1           | good one  
 2             | Marley          | second article |    3        |         2           | waiting for more
```

What I want:

```
articles.id   | articles.writer | articles.text  | comments.id | comments.article_id | comments.comment
 1            | Bob             | first article  |    1        |         1           | i love this article
NULL          | NULL            |    NULL        |    2        |         1           | good one  
 2            | Marley          | second article |    3        |         2           | waiting for more
```

So how do I select each article with its comments and display the article only once not with each comment

Thanks

Comment: On a join, you are combining the results. If you don't want to duplicate I think you'll need 2 queries.

Comment: I think there should be other ways...also  querying inside a php while loop will stop the first query so i think this won't work either...thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use user variables in MySQL to do this:

```
SELECT 
  case when rownum =1 then id else null end id,
  case when rownum =1 then writer else null end writer,
  case when rownum =1 then text else null end text,
  comment
FROM
(
  SELECT a.id, a.writer, a.text,
    c.article_id, c.comment, 
    @rownum := case
                when @prev = a.id
                  and @prev_art = c.article_id
                then @rownum+1 else 1 end rownum,
    @prev := a.id p_id,
    @prev_art := c.article_id p_art
  FROM articles a
  LEFT JOIN comments c
    ON a.id = c.article_id 
  ORDER BY a.id, article_id
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5639/13).

The result is:

```
|     ID | WRITER |           TEXT |             COMMENT |
----------------------------------------------------------
|      1 |    Bob |  first article | i love this article |
| (null) | (null) |         (null) |            good one |
|      2 | Marley | second article |    waiting for more |
```

Edit, if you need the `comment.id`, then you can add it to the result:

```
SELECT 
  case when rownum =1 then id else null end id,
  case when rownum =1 then writer else null end writer,
  case when rownum =1 then text else null end text,
  commentid,
  article_id,
  comment
FROM
(
  SELECT a.id, a.writer, a.text,
    c.article_id, c.comment, c.id commentid,
    @rownum := case
                when @prev = a.id
                  and @prev_art = c.article_id
                then @rownum+1 else 1 end rownum,
    @prev := a.id p_id,
    @prev_art := c.article_id p_art
  FROM articles a
  LEFT JOIN comments c
    ON a.id = c.article_id 
  ORDER BY a.id, article_id
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5639/17).  The result is:

```
|     ID | WRITER |           TEXT | COMMENTID | ARTICLE_ID |             COMMENT |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1 |    Bob |  first article |         1 |          1 | i love this article |
| (null) | (null) |         (null) |         2 |          1 |            good one |
|      2 | Marley | second article |         3 |          2 |    waiting for more |
```

Comment: Now the ID of the second comment is gone and is displayed as null according to your results...

Comment: @Sam this is much easier in other databases that have windowing functions. Then you can apply a row number based on a partition of the data.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel I don't understand, do you need more columns or is this the correct result?  You can add the `comment.id` to the result if needed -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5639/15

Comment: Nope this is not the correct result as the comment id is now missing...i want article info to be outputted only once and then the comments for the article...now the comments id column is muissing from the results...also isn't there a simple way to achieve this?? thanks:)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel all you have to do is add the columns to the query. See my edit

Comment: @MichaelSamuel nope, I don't know of another way to do this